# Laravel page load after redirect takes forever

Tags: database, laravel, sqlite, redirect

does anyone has an idea, why Laravel takes so long to load a page after a redirect? The page loaded after the redirect is just a static page with no further computations or dynamic content.

The page itself processes an excel file, does some computations and has an optional database import (SQLite).

These are the runtimes:

- Without Database Import and with redirect: ca. 6 seconds
- With Database import and without redirect: ca. 7 seconds
- With Database Import and with redirect: ca. 40 seconds

I've implemented the database import both with Eloquent and QueryBuilder...but neither of them has significantly better runtimes.
The computations with and without the database import both take about 6 seconds...the page after the redirect is also displayed immediately after the computations, yet the page loads for another 30-40 seconds.

I'm using

- Laravel 5.5
- SQLite 3.24
- PHP 7.2.4
- The server is just locally started with `php artisan serve`

Comment: If you access the page without a redirect, does it work fine?

Comment: Yeah. Even if I just display a simple "Hello World" on this page it loads like forever

Comment: I've tested it with chrome, safari and firefox. Safari is the only browser where the problem does not occur to such an extent